# LINQ to SQL and immutability

Tags: c#, linq, immutability

I'm tryign to use LINQ to SQL.  Everythign works great but it seems that it is not friendly to immutable objects.

LINQ to SQL requires me to create a parameterless constructor for my immutable class.  But I want it to be immutable, so I want to only allow people to create it with all the required parameters each time.

Likewise I need to have setters on all of my members.

Is there a way that I can still use LINQ 2 SQL without giving up my immutability?

Here is my code:

```
DataContext db = new DataContext("myconnectistring");
Table<MyImmutableType> myImmutableObjects = db.GetTable<MyImmutableType>();
```

It will throw exceptions about no setter and no default constructor with no parameters.

Comment: Could you please specify more in detail what is the problem? What do you want to achieve, what did you try and why it failed?

Comment: @Vlad I put the code that is causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create types *without* this ctor, and simpy use the selector to project into them. Since you obviously aren't using updates etc it shouldn't matter that they aren't part of the generate model:

```
from cust in db.Customers
     ...
     select new ImmutableCust(
         cust.Id, cust.Name, ...);
```

(where ImmutableCust isn't part of the L2S model)

Comment: So do I need to make a storngly typed data context with mutable copies of my classes and then use my immutable ones that I expose to the outside world of my assembly?

Comment: @WCF that should work, yes. Try it on a small example first,  obviously.

Comment: Works like a charm, but of course I need to have double the classes but oh well.