# Linq to SQL: How do I generate Public Get and Protected Set property

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, properties

I'm a newbie to Linq To SQL. I'm generating the classes using SQLMetal. The tool generates Get and Set properties for the Tables and columns of the table.

In my application the Data object can ONLY be updated in the Data Accessor assembly, however the object will be passed on to many other assemblies as they need access to the data. I don't want the data to be modified by external assemblies. I want them to use the GET property to access the data and have a private/internal set.

How do I achieve this? Any standard patterns/practices?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need another immutable class for each table class, into which you can project the data.  Linq to SQL doesn't have a setting that does what you describe, nor does SQLMetal.

The other thing you can do is modify [these T4 templates](http://l2st4.codeplex.com/) to achieve the behavior you describe.  There are other alternatives; micro-ORM's like Dapper or Massive might be a better fit for your situation.

**Further Reading**
[LINQ to SQL and immutability](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4089012/102937)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robert. 

Initially I was thinking of the traditional approach of developing the container classes myself and use stored procedures for select/insert/update of data. That way I have full control over the accessibility of the class. I can create methods that can insert/update the data and have only getter properties so that the data itself is readonly.

In this scenario what would be the best option - Custom implementation of LINQ Or the Traditional approach of data containers?